# One redirect/intermediate page for multiple links and destinations

Tags: java, html, redirect

I have a comparison table on my site, comparing financial products.

Each product has an 'apply now' button which is an external link.

I need a 'you are leaving our site' page before the user actually arrives at external site because we need to notify the user that they are no longer being 'advised' by us.

Which is the best way to tackle this?

I can figure out how to do this for 1 link and 1 redirect page, but i'm wondering if there's a way to have just one page for ALL the links - which 'knows' which page the user is redirecting to?

If i could have a single page called /links that houses all the external links that would be much cleaner.

Thanks

EDIT: In case I havent explained myself clearly, I have found an example:

http://www.fairinvestment.co.uk/fixed_rate_bonds.aspx

All these links seem to pass through the same 'middle' page /links.aspx just with a different query string - this is exactly what i'd like to do, but how?!

Comment: are you using php or asp? usually a server-side language would be the best way to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language you are using but here is what you can do in php:

1) Create a links.php file

2) Put your own styling and HTML in it and then some place add:

```
<a href="<?php $link = $_GET['link']; ?>">Continue to external link</a>
```

3) Then all you have to do is point all your outgoing links to links.php?link=THE_LINK_TO_GO_TO_NEXT

I hope this help :)